# Why don't I see Latin Modern in my tex document?

Tags: fonts, installing, mac, latin-modern

a complete novice question:

I have installed new version of TeX (>3.0) on my Mac (10.7.x). The packages `lm` and `lm-math` are installed (I have checked in TeX Live Utility)

I have put the following code in my `.tex` Abstract document:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This should, according to everything I have read, do it. But when I compile the document, I do not see it in `Latin Modern`! It is just a normal font (I think `Times`). I have tested with commenting out the `\usepackage{lmodern}` line and it is the same font. I do not get any compile error.

Now, my `/Library/fonts` folder does not contain any `lm` fonts. I am trying to copy those from `/usr/local/texlive/2007/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm` to `/Library/fonts` but so far unsuccessful. Should I copy each of the about 50 `lm` fonts that are listed in this folder, to the fonts folder? Please help!

Comment: Check which fonts are embedded in your document from the font tab in the document properties in Adobe reader (Ctrl + D on Windows). Or use pdffonts from a terminal. Latin Modern looks almost identical to Computer Modern, which is what you will get using no font packages on a standard LaTeX installation.

Comment: If you see times then you are loading later a package that change the font to times. But it is not very surprising if the font doesn't change much if you comment out lmodern: The standard cm fonts and lmodern looks quite similar.

Comment: Thak you both so much! The answers have solved my problem!

Comment: The best way to thank the community for answers is to accept and upvote the one that helps you most and upvote any others you find informative.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
foo \textbf{bar}
\end{document}
```

has the embedded fonts:

```
voss@shakira:~> pdffonts foo.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
BTXVOT+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
APJXFQ+LMRoman10-Bold                Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
```